# SLT Transaction LTRS: Error: SQL0104N primary key

Tags: view, slt

We try to create a replication with a view using SLT (SAP Landscape Transformation) Replication Server.

Views need to be defined in LTRS !?

When I try to make such a definition I get the error:

> SQL0104N An unexpected token ")" was found
> following "K" ADD PRIMARY KEY (", Expected tokens
> may include "<unique_col_list>". SQLSTATE=42601

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This error occurs if there is no primary key in the source table.**

Hence the SQL generated by SAP results in an error. Obviously they did not check first if the conditions are met. As a result the error message does only gives an indirect hint.